# navbar: link centered when clicked and entire navbar shifts along w. it? (w. pic)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

I'm using Bootstrap, slim for html, and sass for scss/css.
I also have an external jquery file for .hide() and .show() -ing the different pages when the links are clicked.

I have a div, ".foot-scro" with all the page links in it. (It's effectively my navbar).

It's in the footer so when I say "center" I mean the horizontal center, at the bottom of the page.

It goes page1-link, page2-link...page5-link.

Since the default page (when you load the website) is page1-link, it's color:black while the rest of the links are color:grey.
Then when you click a different link, the page1-link will become grey and the focus (clicked) link will be black.

I want to center the focused link so that the navbar itself shifts along with it.

e.g.:

Say page1-link is the focus, so it's in the center of the page while the other links are on its right. Then user clicks on page3-link. The navbar shifts to the left so that page3-link is now in the center and page1-link and page2-link are on its left and page4-link and page5-link are on its right.

[http://imgur.com/daktXmJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkfEk.png) <-diagram

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hodjjajj/

**CODE:**

**html/slim:**

```
<div class="footer">
    <p id="copyright">
        &#169; 2016 All Rights Reserved
    </p>
    <div class="foot-scro">
        <!--(footer scroll)-->
        <div id="page1-link"> PAGE1 </div>
        <div id="page2-link"> PAGE2 </div>
        <div id="page3-link"> PAGE3 </div>
        <div id="page4-link"> PAGE4 </div>
        <div id="page5-link"> PAGE5 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css/scss/sass:**

```
.footer {
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.footer * {
    display: inline;
}

#copyright {
    margin-left: 50px;
    position:absolute;
}

.foot-scro {
    float: right; 
    width: 600px;
}

.foot-scro div {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 3%;
    color: grey;
}

.foot-scro div:hover {
    color:black;
}

#page1-link {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a Slim->HTML or Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled versions.

Comment: Ok.
I'd translated the Slim into HTML in the JSfiddle file, I'll post that here too.